# Showing form elements dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a web form where the user needs to input the number of hours that they've spent on a task. If they enter 0 hours, I need to show another `TextBox` (without having to post) in an adjacent column, which should be required as long as the hours field remains at 0.

Here is my mark-up now:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th />
        <th class="column-header">Time Spent</th>
        <th class="column-header">Reason for Cancellation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-header">Week 1</th>
        <td>@Html.NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.Week1.TimeSpent)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1.ReasonForCancellation)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-header">Week 2</th>
        <td>@Html.NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.Week2.TimeSpent)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week2.ReasonForCancellation)</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

How can I make the `TextBox` dynamic without posting? I imagine this will require some JavaScript or Ajax but I'm a bit unfamiliar with both (this is my first foray into web forms).

Comment: Is dynamic field going to be model property

Comment: Yes, it is a property on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try somethig like this

```
<tr>
        <th class="row-header">Week 1</th>
        <td>@Html.NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.Week1.TimeSpent)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1.ReasonForCancellation,new { @style="display:none;"})</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-header">Week 2</th>
        <td>@Html.NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.Week2.TimeSpent)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week2.ReasonForCancellation,new { @style="display:none;"})</td>
    </tr>
```

Then you can write script to sense the value of textbox of hour on foucusout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#@Html.FieldIdFor(x => x.Week1.TimeSpent)') .focusout(function() {
   if($(this).val()==0)
{
  $('#@Html.FieldIdFor( x => x.Week1.ThirdProperty)').show();
}

})
</script>
```

same function can be written for week2 hours and show its `ThirdPropery` textbox

If all `NumericTextBoxFor` are going to have `input-time` class

you can write single function from all elements having `input-time` class as

```
$('.input-time').focusout(function(){

  if($(this).val()==0)
   {
          $(this).next().show();
   }
else
   $(this).next().hide();

});
```

Please consider that I am supposing that element you want to show and hide is right next to your `NumericTextBox

Hope it Helps

Comment: "ReasonForCancellation" is the one that I want to show dynamically. So there is no need for the ThirdProperty. :) This looks OK though, except for the hard-coded strings. It seems I would need one script function for each week. Is there any way to make this script more reusable?

Comment: can u tell me NumericTextBoxFor is parsed to which html tag and what is its type. paste that html tag

Comment: <input class="input-time" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TimeSpent must be a number." data-val-required="The TimeSpent field is required." id="Week1_TimeSpent" name="Timesheet.Week1.TimeSpent" type="text" value="0" />